# animate and Iterate in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to animate the all of the following `img`:

```
<img class="image" width="1" src="/assets/vote.gif" alt="option">
<img class="image" width="1" src="/assets/vote.gif" alt="option">
<img class="image" width="1" src="/assets/vote.gif" alt="option">
<img class="image" width="1" src="/assets/vote.gif" alt="option">
```

i want to set different width of the `img` use `jQuery.animate`.

how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extension of the answer above

```
var width = 100;
$("img").each(function() {
$(this).animate({"width": height+"px"}, 1000);
width += 100;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to wrap `this` with `$()`:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    $(this).animate({"width": "100px"}, 1000);
})
```

And by the way, you can do it much simplier:

```
$("img").animate({"width": "100px"}, 1000);
```

Comment: in fact,i want to set different width of the `img`,can you give me some advice?